# Python multiprocessing , code keep on executing?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process , Queue
from datetime import datetime

c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
out = Queue()
def support(m):
    for k in m :
        print "%s <-- hi" % k
    out.put("done")

all = Queue()
temp = []
total = len(c)
count = 0
for m in c :
        count += 1
        total = total - 1
        temp.append(m)
        if count == 5 or total == 0 :
                all.put(temp)
                count = 0
                temp = []

process_count = 3

while all.qsize() != 0 :
    process_list = []
    try :
        for x in range(process_count) :
            p = Process(target=support, args=(all.get(),))
            process_list.append(p)

        for p in process_list :
            p.start()
        for p in process_list :
            p.join()        
    except Exception as e :
       print e

while out.qsize != 0 :
    print out.get()


print "all done"
```

I dont know why it does not end and does not print "all done" , just remain continuously in loop or keep executing .
Will be of great help if you can make this code more efficient but first i want to know why it does not end .

Comment: unrelated: `queue.qsize()` returns the *approximate* size of the queue. You could call `queue.get_nowait()` and catch `Empty` exception instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is:

```
while out.qsize != 0 :
    print out.get()
```

`out.qsize` is a function, so now you're comparing the function itself (not the return value!) with `0`, with is of course always `False`.

You should use:

```
while out.qsize() != 0 :
    print out.get()
```

Comment: thanks buddy , i can say that it is the silliest mistake i had ever done :P , thanks for the help